# Несколько count

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Как можно сделать без цикла несколько count??
Заранее блогодарю ;)

Comment: Уточните вопрос. А то ощущение, что мы на программе "Угадай мелодию"

Comment: Скорее всего вопрос про группировки. @diamond, читайте здесь: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Answer (score 1):

Первая строка связана с третьей, это получение количества из таблицы first, а вторая строка это получение количества из таблицы second.

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `second`)
FROM `first`
```